# trigonometric function integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integral: $$ \int \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}\,dx$$ and I need hint solving it. I tried using the trigonometric identities and let $$u=\sin(x)$$ but I got $$\int ... =\int \dfrac{2u}{1+u^2}\, du$$ which I don't know how to solve. I also tried letting $$u=tg\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ but that leads to $$\int ...=\int \frac{8t(1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)(t^4+6t^2+1)} du$$ which again I can't solve. I'll be glad for help.

Comment: @N.U. $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=sin(2x)$.

Comment: N.U as Git Gud said $$sin(2x)dx=2sin(x)cos(x)dx=[u=sin(x)]2udu$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misread it.

Comment: General remark... if you don't now how to integrate $\int 2u/(1+u^2) du$, then you need to review that material before going on to these trigonometric integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle  \log (u(x))'=\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$, (with the implied assymption that $u(x)>0$ for all $x$ in the domain of $u$).

You should note, however, that $\displaystyle  \log (|u(x)|)'=\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)}$, for all $x\in \operatorname{dom}(u)$ such that $u(x)\neq 0$. Also $1+u^2>0$.

Comment: Now I saw it. thanks.

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Thank you for a question so well posed that it made us easily see how to help you.

Comment: Only half an hour ago I understood that there is no differnce between LaTex and MathJax writing so hopefully my questions will not be gibberish anymore :)

Comment: By the way, what is $$dom(u)$$?

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner The domain of the function $u$.

Answer (score 3):

@Git Gud's answer is absolutely complete but there is a good point about these kinds of integral:

> If you have $\int R(\sin x,\cos x)dx$ and $R(-\sin x,-\cos x)=R(\sin x,\cos x)$ then use $\tan x=t$ as a good substitution.